# "Wie eine Hyperbel ansteigen"

Tags: idiom

Im Buch Werner Faulstich: Mediengeschichte von den Anfängen bis 1700; 2006, findet sich auf Seite 123 der folgende Absatz:

> Eng damit zusammenzuhängen scheint ein Befund, der sich auf einen weiteren, nicht minder verbreiteten  [...] Irrtum bezieht, [..]: Demnach soll die Zahl der Medien [...] wie eine Hyperbel angestiegen sein [...] Tatsächlich ist festzuhalten, dass Medien numerisch nur wenige Veränderungen erfahren: Für die archaische Periode lassen scih mindestens 15 Medien nachweisen, [...] für das christliche Mittelalter erneut 15, und für die frühe Neuzeit 20 [...].

Was bedeutet "wie eine Hyperbel ansteigen"? Mathematisch gesehen würde ich nicht den Graph einer Hyperbel als Beispiel für "großes Wachstum" ansehen. Ist etwas anderes damit gemeint?

Comment: Eine Hyperbel nähert sich mit ihrer Steigung einer Asymptote an. Dann wäre mit der Formulierung gemeint, dass die Zahl der Medien erst langsam und dann zwar immer stärker ansteigt, aber auf lange Zeit gesehen doch "nur noch" konstant ansteigt (da dann keine Kurve mehr sondern nur noch eine Gerade).

Comment: Was würdest du denn als Graph für "großes Wachstum" ansehen?

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Jede beliebige [Ackermannfunktion](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermannfunktion) wäre ein gutes Beispiel für großes Wachstum. Folgen, die man bei der Berechnung von [Grahams Zahl](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grahams_Zahl) verwendet, wachsen aber noch erheblich extremer. (Da geht es um Funktionen, die sind so schnell wachsen, dass bereits ab der 4. oder 5. Iterationsstufe die Anzahl der Stellen der Zahl, die die Anzahl der Stellen der eigentliche Zahl angibt, größer ist als die Zahl der Elementarteilchen im sichtbaren Universum.)

Comment: @Hubert   Das ist interessant, vielen Dank. Hübsch, diese Ackermannfunktionen. Jedoch, für den Text in der Eingangsfrage ist "wie eine Hyperbel" vielleicht doch besser, denn mit "wie eine Ackermannfunktion" könnten nicht so viele Leute was anfangen, während eine Hyperbel vermutlich jeder wenigstens mal in der Schule gemalt hat. Außerdem steigt die Zahl der Medien (in dieser Untersuchung) vielleicht wirklich eher wie eine Hyperbel an, und nicht so superduperüberextrem wie eine Ackermannfunktion?

Comment: Die Mutter aller Hyperbeln, (1/x), steigt ja gar nicht an, sondern fällt. Kann es sein, dass eine Parabel gemeint ist, und der Autor sich einfach vertan hat?

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Eine Exponentialfunktion - die steigt immer weiter steiler an.

Comment: @userunknown: Ja, ich glaube auch, dass da jemand besonders gescheit daherreden wollte, und dann zu Wörtern gegriffen hat, die er selber nicht versteht. So etwas ist immer peinlich. Besonders peinlich finde ich das, wenn Leute, die aufgrund ihrer Ausbildung eigentlich wissen müssten, wovon sie reden, manche Begriffe trotzdem falsch verwenden. Beispiel Quantensprung: In der Physik ist ein Quantensprung die kleinstmögliche Zustandsänderung. ...

Comment: (Forts.:) Noch näher kann man nicht am Stillstand dran sein. Und trotzdem gibt es Politiker, die das immer wieder sagen. Darunter sogar eine promovierte Physikerin, die eine Doktorarbeit über Quantenchemie geschrieben hat: http://www.n-tv.de/ticker/Merkel-sieht-Quantensprung-fuer-Euro-Stabilitaet-article1818571.html

Comment: @user unknown Wenn x gegen Null geht gibt es aber doch einen starken Anstieg bei dieser Hyperbel. Trotzdem ist der zitierte Text katastrophal.

Comment: @Hubert   Die Kritik an der Verwendung von "Quantensprung" für "Schritt nach vorn in eine neue Stufe" ist natürlich richtig (und auch schon oft geäußert). Trotzdem kann ich auch Verständnis aufbringen für diesen Gebrauch. Wenn man nämlich mit einem (imaginären) Mikroskop gaaaaanz dicht rangeht an die Quanten (bildlich gesprochen; Hinweis auf die Schiefheit des Bildes ist unnötig), dann ist der Sprung von einem Zustand zum anderen schon ein ganz erheblicher und eben ein **alles verändernder**, nicht etwa nur gradueller. Und das meinen jene, die so von "Quantensprung" reden, ja eigentlich.

Comment: @MartinPeters: Habe ich auch bedacht, aber wenn man nichts dazusagt, dann liest man einen solchen Graphen von links nach rechts. Die Zeitscala, auf die man sich hier bezieht, zeichnet man ja auch von und nicht nach 0. Mit entsprechenden Zusätzen wie v.a. Vorzeichen lässt sich ein solcher Graph ja mannigfach manipulieren - allein als Bild, einen Sachverhalt zu veranschaulichen, funktioniert dann nicht mehr, wenn man die Bedeutung schon richtig verstanden haben muss, um sich das passende vorzustellen.

Answer (score 1):

Das Wort "Hyperbel" hat nicht nur eine mathematische Bedeutung, sondern bedeutet auch "Übertreibung":

> In der Sprachwissenschaft bezeichnet man als Hyperbel (, von ὑπερβάλλειν hyperballein ‚über das Ziel hinaus werfen‘) das rhetorische Stilmittel der Übertreibung.

(https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbel_(Sprache))

Was sich der Autor dabei gedacht hat, kann ich dir freilich nicht sagen. Es ist durchaus denkbar, dass er "übertrieben angestiegen seien" sagen wollte und nur etwas schlauer wirken wollte.

Auch ist es in manchen Sprachen (u.A. im Deutschen) üblich, starke Anstiege als *exponentiell* zu bezeichnen, selbst dann, wenn sie offensichtlich keiner exponentiellen Natur sind. Dementsprechend ist es auch möglich, dass er das schreiben wollte, aber hier etwas schlauer wirken wollte.

Letztlich ist es unwichtig, was sich der Autor dabei gedacht hat, denn zum einen ist klar, was er meinte, und zum anderen ergibt es keinen Sinn, nach der vermeintlichen Bedeutung von etwas zu forschen, das sich jemand mal ausgedacht hat, das aber kein anderer Muttersprachler verwendet oder auch nur ohne erklärenden Kontext versteht. Dient etwas nicht der Beschreibung, sondern muss bei jeder Verwendung beschrieben werden, so ist es meiner Meinung nach nicht teil einer Sprache, denn Sprachen dienen der Beschreibung.